# Formula for finding and replacing text in Excel cells if a prior condition is met?

Tags: excel, text, conditional-statements, formula

I would like to apply a formula to a spreadsheet that looks through Column E and removes or replaces text based on certain conditions.

In this case,

If the text is the cell is  F U and the cell immediately above contains a single  F (on its own) - then change the text in the target cell from  F U  to F S

If the text in the target cell is  F U in any other condition, then replace with 
 an F

If the Text in any cell is  F C U then replace with F C

I am supposed to use a formula to achieve this,but I can't work out how to achieve the logical loop involved.

Any help gratefully received

Thanks

***Screen of current spreadsheet:***

[image]

Comment: Use a helper column and nested if statements

Comment: If() as suggested with substitute() ...